# Find all $n$ such $\sigma(n) = 546$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

Find all $n$ such $\sigma(n) = 546$. I find $n = 180$ is an answer. But I know there is more. I tried to used the formula $$\sigma(n) = \frac{{p_1}^{a_1 + 1} - 1}{p_1 - 1} \ldots \frac{{p_k}^{a_k + 1} - 1}{p_k - 1}.$$ But I got stuck to make a way to find the other $n$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We find that $n\in \{180, 234, 362, 369\}$. For the proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419585/find-all-n-such-that-sigman-12?rq=1), and similar questions, e.g., [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805743/find-all-the-natural-numbers-n-such-that-sigman-15?rq=1). Also the question about [$\sigma(n)=165$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991007/find-all-k-such-that-sigma-k-165-where-sigma-is-the-sum-of-divisors) has helpful answers.